# How to join two table using Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, criteria

Right now I am querying all records from the Employee table using the Criteria Hibernate query and it works fine.
I need to join Employee Table with Library Table where Library.Emp_Id = Employee.Emp_id and do I need to fetch all the records from the Employee table and book title and checkout date from library table as part of joined select query. How can I do that?

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteria = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
  Root<Employee> root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
  responseList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
  return responseList
```

Answer (score 0):

This would look similar to the following:

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
  Root<Employee> root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
  Root<Library> library = criteria.from(Library.class);
  criteria.where(builder.eq(root.get("id"), library.get("employeeId")));
  criteria.multiselect(root, library);
  responseList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```